# The select style of the list sticks out of the border

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using next.js and mui (material-ui) in my project. The component is written in the following structure.

```
<Paper>
  <List>
  ..
  </List>
</Paper>
```

When the list is scrolled, there is a problem that the select style of the `<ListItemButton>` component is out of the  component's rounded border.

[image]

How can I apply border-radius to `<ListItemButton>` component to view it naturally when scroll occurred? or Is there another CSS trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a CSS thing. You want the wrapper to have `overflow: hidden` applied ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)). Otherwise the children `li` elements have their background color bleed out.

See below for an example:

```css
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

/* Misc */
.list li { padding: 4px }
.list li:nth-child(odd)  { background-color: cyan }
.list li:nth-child(even) { background-color: lime }

p { margin-bottom: 2px }

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>This does <em>not</em> have <code>`overflow: hidden`</code> on the parent <code>ul</code>.</p>
<ul class="list">
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>sit</li>
</ul>

<p>This <em>does</em> have <code>`overflow: hidden`</code> on the parent <code>ul</code>.</p>
<ul class="list overflow">
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>sit</li>
</ul>
```